# Simply resize a multi-line math equation

Tags: fonts, equations, pdftex, texmaker

I am having a hard and frustrating time trying to very simply resize a multiline math equation. I have this code here:

```
\begin{gather}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather}
```

This works fine, and is centered in the page. However, now based on this, I would simply like to make the *equation as it renders on the PDF, larger*, and have control over that.

How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You can change the font size before entering the `gather` environment and put all this in a group, e.g. `{\Large\begin{gather} ... \end{gather}}`, but the equation number will also set Large.

Comment: @Bernard How do I remove the equation number altogether?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond - Change both instances of `gather` to `gather*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the equation number by using `gather*` and change size using the standard commands.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\large
\begin{gather*}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather*}

\Large
\begin{gather*}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather*}

\huge
\begin{gather*}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather*}

\Huge
\begin{gather*}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: @Mico you are right. I just default to it as it is what I use most often, and it avoids the extra line. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you Dan, this I think does it for me. For completeness, is there a way in which one can control the size in a continuous manner? (As in, with a number?) thanks

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond I am not sure how to do it within the gather environment, but with a single equation you can do something like `\resizebox{.5\hsize}{!}{$f(y) = a \cdot k^{y}$}`. This requires the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by *make the equation as it renders on the PDF, larger,* but here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\NewEnviron{gather+}[1][1]{%
  \begin{equation*}
  \scalebox{#1}{$\begin{gathered}\BODY\end{gathered}$}
  \end{equation*}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather+}
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather+}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather+}[1.5]
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather+}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather+}[0.7]
f(y) = a \cdot k^{y} \\
\theta = 0
\end{gather+}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]